# Showing that a sequence $f_n(x)$ is orthogonal in $C[a, b]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Can somebody tell me what one would have to do to ascertain that a sequence of functions is orthogonal in this space?  What does it entail?

I am looking for a template on how to do this.

I do not have a particular sequence in mind, just generally.  However, I can provide a concrete example if it helps.

Comment: Do you want to check whether a system is orthogonal, or do you want to produce an orthogonal system?

Answer (score 0):

The functions $f_n$ are orthogonal with respect to weight $w(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$  if $$\int_a^b \overline{f_n(x)} f_m(x) w(x)\; dx = 0$$ for $m \ne n$.  If no weight function is specified, it would be taken to be $1$.

An orthogonal sequence is often constructed as eigenfunctions of a Sturm-Liouville operator.